# Broken dependencies after trying to uninstall nvidia-390

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dependencies

I tried to uninstall the `nvidia-390` driver, it failed and now I have unmet dependencies.  When I try `sudo apt --fix-broken install` this is what I see:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 29.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 147 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 
libnvidia-gl-390 i386 390.48-0ubuntu3 [14.9 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 
libnvidia-gl-390 amd64 390.48-0ubuntu3 [14.3 MB]
Fetched 29.1 MB in 16s (1,771 kB/s)                                            
(Reading database ... 146918 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-390_390.48-0ubuntu3_i386.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-
linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by 
libnvidia-gl-390'
found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to 
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-
390_390.48-0ubuntu3_i386.deb (--unpack):
new libnvidia-gl-390:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess 
returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-390_390.48-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-
linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by 
libnvidia-gl-390'
found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-
390_390.48-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
new libnvidia-gl-390:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess 
returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.48-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.48-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ sudo apt-get remove nvidia-390
Package 'nvidia-390' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-ifr1-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

What has happened?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a similar broken dependency problem by first running this:

```
sudo apt remove nvidia-*
```

That didn't work but before failing it gave me a list of all the packages that were going to be removed. I used that in conjunction with dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -r xxx
```

replacing xxx by the names listed before. A few packages gave an error because they weren't actually installed, but the others got removed. Then I did:

```
sudo apt install
sudo apt autoremove
```

and everything was back to normal.